# Calculus: existence of global maximum and global minimum for $f(x)=e^x\cdot x^3$

Tags: calculus, optimization

$$f(x)=e^x\cdot x^3$$

How do i know if there exists global max and min if domain is from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$? Does there exist global max and min?

Comment: Are you familiar with calculating derivatives of the product of two functions $f(x) * g(x)$?

Comment: From visualizing this function, it seems there should be a global minimum, but no global maximum. For a function like this one (that is not terribly complicated, and is clearly differentiable on its domain), taking derivatives and using the second derivative test to find the maxima/minima seems like the best approach for finding these.

Comment: What is $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)?$ Does this tell you something about the global maximum? Now, what is $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)?$ Does this tell you something about the global minimum? (Note that $f$ is continuous.)

Comment: Use, $$(uv)' = u'v + uv'$$ to find the first derivative. Use that to find the extrema and then use the second derivative test. Let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: @GeorgeCoote He/She is not asked to find the extrema. He/She is asked about existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT.- $f'(x)=e^xx^2(x+3)=0\Rightarrow x=0,-3,-\infty$ and $f'(x)\gt0$ for $x\gt0$. You can deduce from this that a global minimum is taken at $x=-3$ and that there is not a global maximum (or it is $+\infty$ if you want).

Comment: Okay.. And x=0,−3,−∞ are the stationary(critical) points?

Comment: $x \to -\infty$ would give an infimum or a supremum, not a maximum or minimum. For example $f(x) = \mathrm e^x$ has no minimum, although its infimum is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note:
$$f(0)=0$$
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)=0$$
$$f(x)<0, x<0$$
and the function is continuous, so there is a global min at the interval $x<0$.

There is no global max because:
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)=+\infty.$$